# How to drill into SOAP Namespaces with SimpleXML & PHP

Tags: php, soap, simplexml

All,

I am trying to access element ebl:RequesterCredentials in a SOAP response but having no success so far. I am using PHP SimpleXML. The issue for me at least is registering the ebl namespace - All I am getting in the response is this:

xmlns=”urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents”

I Tried this:

```
$r =     $xml->registerXPathNamespace("ebl","urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents");
foreach($xml->xpath('ebl:RequesterCredentials') as $e){
$sig = (string) $e->NotificationSignature;

}
```

The element is nested as such:

soapenv:Envelope -> soapenv:Header -> ebl:RequesterCredentials -> ebl:NotificationSignature

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <ebl:RequesterCredentials xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0">
            <ebl:NotificationSignature xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">9hJXr9QTtck33I/4wg135A==</ebl:NotificationSignature>
        </ebl:RequesterCredentials>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <GetMemberMessagesResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
        <Message>FOO</Message>
        <Timestamp>2007-09-14T17:07:41.984Z</Timestamp>
    </GetMemberMessagesResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Any ideas on how to access this element?

Comment: $h = $xml->xpath('/soapenv:Header/ebl:RequesterCredentials');

Answer (score 0):

After several different attempts to access the element value, this got me what I needed, although it's probably way too verbose.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(...);
$sig = (string) $xml->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->children('urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents')->RequesterCredentials->NotificationSignature;
```